Iterative process simpler form
Is it possible to convert this recurrent relation that can be computed iteratively to some form that is possible to calculate without iterations?
Iter1:
$$\frac{x_{11}}{c*a_{11}}=\alpha_{11}$$
$$\frac{x_{11}}{c*b_{11}}=\beta_{11}$$
$$\frac{x_{12}}{c*a_{12}}=\alpha_{12}$$
$$\frac{x_{12}}{c*b_{12}}=\beta_{12}$$
$$\alpha = min(\alpha_{11},\alpha_{12})$$
$$\beta = min(\beta_{11},\beta_{12})$$
then we calculate:
$$x_{11} - \alpha*a_{11} + \beta*b_{11} = x_{21}$$
$$x_{12} - \alpha*a_{12} + \beta*b_{12} = x_{22}$$
Iter2:
$$\frac{x_{21}}{c*a_{11}}=\alpha_{11}$$
$$\frac{x_{21}}{c*b_{11}}=\beta_{11}$$
$$\frac{x_{22}}{c*a_{12}}=\alpha_{12}$$
$$\frac{x_{22}}{c*b_{12}}=\beta_{12}$$
$$\alpha = min(\alpha_{11},\alpha_{12})$$
$$\beta = min(\beta_{11},\beta_{12})$$
then we calculate:
$$x_{21} - \alpha*a_{11} + \beta*b_{11} = x_{31}$$
$$x_{22} - \alpha*a_{12} + \beta*b_{12} = x_{32}$$
iteration ends when $x_{n1}$ or $x_{n2}$ is close to 0.
As you can see, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are calculated based on new result of $x_{n1}$ or $x_{n2}$ at each step.
